# Database disk image is malformed from many concurrent writes

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm running many (18k) batch jobs on a cluster with a Lustre filesystem. The jobs are submitted at the same time, each takes about 3 seconds, and they write the result using the `sqlite3` python module. The write part of the code is very simple:

```
with sqlite3.connect(name, timeout=900) as conn: 
    conn.execute(
        "insert into someTable values (?, ?)", (value1, value2))
```

but a lot of the jobs will throw an exception:

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

and sometimes

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with lots of jobs putting a lock on the file when they write to it, but my impression was that `sqlite3` should know to wait patiently for the file to be free. Is my error likely a result of too many concurrent writes? How can I fix it?

Comment: Afaik, sqlite doesn't support concurrent writings.

Comment: Better to not use sqlite3; use real db like postgresql instead, might end up saving quite a some time...

Comment: @RapolasK.: yes it does.

Comment: Are you storing the database on a network drive?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Lustre filesystem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite does **not** support storage on a distributed file system. Concurrent access required locking and that is not transferred across such a system.

You'll have to move to a database that supports a networked model instead, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: that's disappointing, I guess I'll fall back on the old method (each job writes output to it's own file, aggregate later)